# Can I buy a copy of Planescape Torment digitally from anywhere these days?

Tags: planescape-torment

Or am I restricted to second hand?

Comment: It's [second on the "Most Wanted" list](http://www.gog.com/en/wanted/) on Good Old Games, so it will probably be there one day, but not currently.

Comment: I've never heard of this game before today. A friend was telling me this morning by email. How strange! Is it getting lots of love on the tubes somewhere? I heard it's superb.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about where to buy a game.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit: As mentioned by LessPop_MoreFizz, as of today (9/28/10) you can get Planescape: Torment from GoG. [Buy it now!](http://www.gog.com/game/planescape_torment)**

OLD ANSWER: It's not available digitally anywhere.  As Daemonic mentioned, keep an eye on [Gog.com](http://gog.com). It'll probably show up there before anywhere else.

In the meantime, it's VERY findable on [Ebay](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw=planescape+torment&_sacat=0&_odkw=planescape&_osacat=0&bkBtn=&_trksid=p3286.m270.l1313).

Comment: Does it run without hassle on modern hardware / OS?

Comment: I think so. Here's a handle little guide for installing it on modern OSes. http://thunderpeel2001.blogspot.com/2009/01/planescape-torment-fully-modded.html

Comment: If/when GoG get's it all their games are set up to run on modern systems.

Answer (score 20):

As of today (9/28/2010), Planescape Torment is availiable from [Good Ol' Games,](http://www.gog.com) for the low low price of $9.99, complete with some fun new bonus material.

Comment: Keep in mind that gog.com has [an article for recommend mods](http://www.gog.com/forum/general/mod_spotlight_planescape_torment_mods_guide) before starting a new game.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is mostly available second hand.  As mentioned in an above comment, it's on the most wanted list for Good Old Games.